# Wordpress Custom Permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have an issue with Wordpress permalinks.

I created a Wordpress website offline, using EasyPhp WebServer 14.1. In this website, my pages had default names, like : **?p=123**

After putting it online, I created an empty .htaccess file at the root of the folder, with 777 rights (just to be sure it could be written). Then I changed the permalink option into "name article".

The .htaccess file has been modified, it contains now :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However, all the pages (each of them but the home page) can't be found. I get something like

> Oops ! That page can't be found. It looks like nothing was found at
>   this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?

The website URL is : http://www.vogliadimare.fr

What did I do wrong ? Where could this come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled

Comment: according to the web hosting site, it is...

Comment: If you're not totally sure (if it is, or how to check), you can for instance add some garbage after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and see if you get an http 500 error

Comment: yep, after adding some garbage I got the http 500 error

Comment: Ok, good point. Then the problem comes from WP

Comment: I verified wp-options, permalink_structure is set to /%postname%/. So it seems to be correct. Moreover, in the table wp_redirection_404, I have the log of the errors I got...

Comment: Is there something interesting in those logs ? You should be able to find somewhere why WP does not find pages. Ps: i just tested it with a local WP and it's working without any problem (changing it from default `?=123` to personalised structure, and back to default)

Comment: I'm not sure how to read it...the URL is the asked URL, and the referrer is the page it was triggered from ?

Comment: Just tried with my local WP and I have the same problem too !!! You must be right, it definitely comes from my WP ! I also try to shut down all my plugins, but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Please test :

1) Edit **httpd.conf** and following steps:

2) Search and replace :

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to --> (Remove #)
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

3)Search and replace :

`AllowOverride None` to --> `AllowOverride All`

4) Restart services from your Local Server

5) Refresh permalinks , set permalink_structure and save configuration, again set permalink_structure  /%postname%/ and save.

Good Luck

Comment: oops I dit it wrong...in fact I get an Internal Server Error !

Comment: Please remove AllowOverride All(.htaccess) but set permalink again .

Comment: Done a thousand of times, nothing changes...btw, AllowOverride is not an instruction for .htaccess but for httpd.conf.

Comment: Please review my new edit, I happened to my same in test work and this was the solution